# Converting ColumnRefs to PersistentPaths

Tags: guidewire, gosu

The following query is supposed to return a list of `PolicyNumber`s and `ReportYear`s along with the total number of exposures for each of the 'categories':

```
var query = Query.make(Exposure)
var resultSet = query.select({
    QuerySelectColumns.pathWithAlias("PolicyNumber", Paths.make(Exposure#Claim, Claim#Policy, Policy#PolicyNumber)),

    // Illegal
    QuerySelectColumns.dbFunctionWithAlias("ReportYear", DBFunction.DatePart(DatePart.YEAR, Paths.make(Exposure#Claim, Claim#ReportedDate))),

    QuerySelectColumns.dbFunctionWithAlias("ExposureCount", DBFunction.Count(Paths.make(Exposure#ID)))
})
```

However, the code does not compile because the signature of `DBFunction.DatePart` is `DatePart(gw.api.database.DatePart, gw.api.database.ColumnRef)`, and the type of the path specifier `Paths.make(Exposure#Claim, Claim#ReportedDate)` is `gw.api.path.PersistentPath<Exposure, Date>`. Is there any way to access the `Claim#ReportedDate` field so that it is possible to later use it in a call to `DatePart`?

Judging by the fact that `DBFunction.Count` (but also `DBFunction.Sum`, `DBFunction.Min`, `DBFunction.Max`, etc.) does have a version that takes a path of type `PersistentPath` (see `ExposureCount`), I expected that it would be possible to overload `DatePart` using reflection, in the same way in which `Count(PersistentPath<KeyableBean, Object>)` is implemented in `gw.api.database.GWDBFunctionEnhancement`, but, unfortunately, `Count(PersistentPath<KeyableBean, Object>)` resolves to `Count(List<IEntityPropertyInfo>)`. That is, it seems that – in order to provide the missing function – the class `DBFunction` would have to define a function of type `DatePart(DatePart, List<IEntityPropertyInfo>)` (or at least `DatePart(DatePart, IEntityPropertyInfo`), but this is also missing. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: So you are trying to find the number of exposures that exist for every unique `{PolicyNumber, ClaimReported (Year)}` combination? I'll look at this a bit tomorrow and let you know if I have any better luck. Your analysis seems spot on that this is a missing capability for aggregate functions in row queries.

Comment: 1/2 It may turn to be of little use because I cannot test it now, but, going through the Guidewire ClaimCenter 10.0.3 Gosu Reference Guide, I found two code examples showing how to build a query that returns all addresses within ten miles of San Mateo along with their respective distances from San Mateo in miles (pp. 367-368). The first of the examples seems rather uninteresting, but the second one calculates the distances using the expression `QuerySelectColumns.dbFunctionWithAlias("Distance", DBFunction.Distance(personQuery, "Person.PrimaryAddress.SpatialPoint"))`, where `personQuery`

Comment: 2/2 is the primary query, and the `Person.PrimaryAddress.SpatialPoint` string pinpoints the primary address. I'm almost sure that `DatePart` does not have such capabilities, but this is exactly what I need.

Comment: And yes, in pure SQL, the query would be something like `SELECT cc_policy.PolicyNumber, DATEPART(yyyy, cc_claim.ReportedDate), COUNT(cc_exposure.ID)
FROM cc_exposure INNER JOIN ...
GROUP BY cc_policy.PolicyNumber, DATEPART(yyyy, cc_claim.ReportedDate)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get almost everything you want from this query without using the DatePart dbFunction.  Just return the date and the result will be aggreggated by PolicyNumber and ReportedDate.  It's possible that will be close enough considering that there will be few claims for a given policyNumber.  If it's necessary you can convert the result set into a typed array and do the final aggregation in Gosu code.

Alternatively you can convert this into an entity query (where the DatePart should work) and use Gosu on the result set to print the desired columns.  If this is the case consider defining a ViewEntity to include the join in a trivial way.

You could also experiment with the "expr" DBFunction to see if you can get the results of what you're trying to do using raw SQL operations.  That may allow you to combine Paths and ColumnRefs in a way that will work.

Unfortunately the DatePart DBFunction doesn't appear to be compatible with row queries.

Finally, this is trivial to produce from a BI solution.  Can the production of this data set be removed from the ClaimCenter runtime?

Comment: All of these are good suggestions from Marty. I would just emphasize the last suggestion. The query builder API in ClaimCenter is meant to be used within the application for application tasks, it is less effective when trying to use it for enterprise reporting tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not related to reporting and really needs to be done by the server.  I can confirm that using an array works fine, but I haven't had the time to try the other two approaches yet. I hope that, by using `Expr`, I'll be able to go beyond "fine" to "great", but I may not be able to test it until the weekend.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to exposure count for every PolicyNumber/YearReported combination? The only time I have seen something similar to this is during a final audit in PC for Worker's Comp policies where PC is trying to see if the deductible was met for the company's WC policy. Marty or I might be able to provide a better answer if we knew the business context.

Comment: The business context is just that one of our claims management systems simply doesn't have the concept of exposure, and the basic rule is that what that (external) system calls a claim, CC would (or could) represent as an exposure. While in the claim intake process, the external system is supposed to show `ExposureCount` to the adjuster to remind them that the policy that's being using may not be known exclusively to the external system and that it is possible that the loss history information displayed in the system may be incomplete.

Comment: But the question really is only about converting `ColumnRef`s to `PersistentPath`s. (If I could, I'd tag it `query-api`.)

Comment: So there is an external claims system that is still opening new claims currently and during the claims intake process it needs to know how many exposures (in the ClaimCenter vocabulary) have been opened for a particular policy number, by calendar year. If the external system is retrieving this information from ClaimCenter via a webservice exposed by ClaimCenter, I think pulling the results into an array might be acceptable (from a performance perspective) if you are limiting each webservice call by requiring a policy number be provided.

Comment: I know this was not your original question, but the best solution here might be in changing the integration pattern you are using instead of trying to optimize this query. Does the integration between ClaimCenter and the external claims system need to be synchronous? Can the exposure count information be populated in the external claims system in an overnight batch? Does the exposure count data need to be accurate up to the second or can it be delayed a day? The answers to these questions are probably more important than how to pull this data via query-api.

Comment: All the data is indeed supposed to be collected in an overnight batch so I still think that it would be best if all the grouping was done by the database, but the exposure query I included in my question is only an excerpt. The results do not need to be accurate up to the second, but – when the full query is considered – even the array approach to aggregating (and then counting) the exposures turns a bit impractical because there are some other columns, and the grouped exposures must be stored in a multi-key map.